# Other Android developer copied my app content and made a new app

Tags: google-play

My app is live and other Android developer copied all the content of my app and made a new app and the design of the app is also same as my Android app. All The content of the new app is duplicate content of my old app. How to go further in this issue.

Comment: Can you paste a link to google play of your app and the dupe?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advice and appstore policy enforcement, not programming.

Comment: I need to get permission from my client to provide the app details and I'm hundred percent sure that this new app contain all our data.

Comment: I think you best bet is to contact a lawyer or Google itself, so the dupe app can be taken down.

Comment: Report the cloned app at google play and explain the reason. You have the upload-date of your app and this is the evidence. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

If you believe that your copyrighted content has been distributed on Google Play Store without your permission, please feel free to report a policy violation of the Google Play Developer Distribution Agreement: https://support.google.com/legal/answer/3110420?product=androidmarket.

Google Play team will be able to assist you further.

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1085703?hl=en